# Debugging with VS 2010 in IIS 7 classic pipeline

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I am trying to debug an ASP.NET website in VS 2010. The website is running in classic pipeline mode in IIS 7 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine. For some reason my breakpoints are never hit. I use the attach to process method to attach to the w3wp.exe process. I do not have enable 32 bit application enabled on the app pool. If i use the integrated mode it does work. i would rather use the classic mode since my production server runs IIS 6.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by selecting the "Attach to" as "managed 2.0" in the "Attach to process" dialog. Never had this issue with vs 2008.