# How to register an HttpModule suitable for VS2012 Cassini and IIS7?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7, httpmodule, cassini

i have a simple `IHttpModule`:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace DummyPlaceholder
{
    class PerformanceHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And you register **HttpModules** inside `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpModules>
         <add name="PerformanceHttpModule" type="DummyPlaceholder.PerformanceHttpModule"/>
      </httpModules>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When i was developing, and testing locally inside my Visual Studio 2012 integrated ("Cassini") web-server, everything worked great.

When it came time to deploy to a live IIS7 web-server, the server would [give a **500 Internal Server Error**, and absolutely no information about the cause anywhere.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573325/500-internal-server-error-when-adding-httpmodule-in-my-website)

The issue is that IIS7 changed how you register **HttpModules**, you no longer use `system.web`, instead you must now use `system.webServer`:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <modules>
         <add name="PerformanceHttpModule" type="DummyPlaceholder.PerformanceHttpModule"/>
      </modules>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And now that works on IIS, but doesn't work inside Visual Studio 2012.

What i need is a solution that works in both, without having to modify the `web.config` file when it is being published.

The issue is that IIS7 and newer, have a new ***"Integrated"*** mode. The alternative mode is the behavior that IIS6 had, called ***"Classic"*** mode.

Obviously i need to put the Visual Studio integrated web-server into ***"Integrated"*** mode, so that it look at:

```
configuration/webServer/modules
```

for modules.

How do i do that?

## Bonus Reading

- ["500 Internal Server Error" when adding HttpModule in my Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573325/500-internal-server-error-when-adding-httpmodule-in-my-website)
- [Not understanding IIS Classic and Integrated Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492067/not-understanding-iis-classic-and-integrated-mode)
- [Debugging with VS 2010 in IIS 7 classic pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111676/debugging-with-vs-2010-in-iis-7-classic-pipeline)
- [HTTP handlers in IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621265/http-handlers-in-iis6-or-iis7-classic-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a guy from the Cassini project explaining that [*"Integrated"* modules will never be supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708187/vs2010-development-web-server-does-not-use-integrated-mode-http-handlers-modules).

And among the dozen or so questions of people suffering with this problem, there was a hack solution:

- [remove the module as you add the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963545/httpmodule-not-running-with-visual-studio)

You issue a `remove` to remove the `system.web/httpModule`, before you add the `system.webServer/module` module.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpModules>
         <add name="PerformanceHttpModule" type="DummyPlaceholder.PerformanceHttpModule"/>
      </httpModules>
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
      <modules>
         <remove name="PerformanceHttpModule" />
         <add name="PerformanceHttpModule" type="DummyPlaceholder.PerformanceHttpModule"/>
      </modules>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- Cassini only supports the first syntax, but doesn't understand or crash on the second
- IIS only understand the second syntax, and crashes on the first
- With their powers combined, you get a system as well thought out as Tomcat and WebSphere.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct Integrated Pipeline Mode on IIS7 to not validate the configuration (i.e., not raise an exception if there is content in the `<httpModules>` element).  Put a `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />` in your `<system.webServer>` element.

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/validation

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpModules>
         <add name="PerformanceHttpModule" type="DummyPlaceholder.PerformanceHttpModule"/>
      </httpModules>
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
      <modules>
         <remove name="PerformanceHttpModule" />
         <add name="PerformanceHttpModule" type="DummyPlaceholder.PerformanceHttpModule"/>
      </modules>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```